# How to get max count of referral to a root node in a tree

Tags: sql, postgresql, tree, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I've a table with users by structure like this:

```
id   name  parent_id
1    Mike     
2    Jack     1
3    Sam      1
4    Kurt     1
5    Somebody 3
6    Tommy    4
6    etc..    2
```

How to get a max count of referral on first level nesting per user, by this example I expect result:

```
3 because Jack, Sam, Kurt is a referral of Mike on first level
```

Comment: Please define your question properly. How is "first level" defined? By `parent_id IS NULL`? Add a table definition and your Postgres version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "first level" is defined by `parent_id IS NULL` and the current version Postgres 9.4:

```
SELECT parent_id, count(*) AS referral_ct
FROM  (
   SELECT id AS parent_id
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  t1.parent_id IS NULL
   ) t1
JOIN   tbl t2 USING (parent_id)
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 2 DESC
LIMIT  1;  -- to only get 1 row with max. referral_ct
```

With only few root nodes, `JOIN LATERAL` may be faster:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.referral_ct
FROM  (
   SELECT id
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  parent_id IS NULL
   ) t1
LEFT  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT parent_id, count(*) AS referral_ct
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  parent_id = t1.id
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) t2 ON true
ORDER   BY 2 DESC
LIMIT   1;  -- to only get 1 row with max. referral_ct
```

Related, with more explanation:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Comment: Yes! That it ;) Thx!
Can you help me fix this code in order to get a count of referral on 3 level nesting per user or that impossible ? I expect result of 6.

Comment: Please ask a new question for a new question, comments are not the place. This question is also still lacking information.